# Retrieve PFUser Photo

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

Is it possible to retrieve a PFUser's photo saved in the column "profilePhoto" without an additional API call?

For example, you can fetch the user's username with: `PFUser.currentUser().username`

But `PFUser.currentUser().profilePhoto` does not work (custom column)

If an API call is needed, what is the correct way to fetch the profile photo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an API call because when the login is completed, yes there is an API call, but it will only ever get the standard details.

So, you need to use one of the methods like `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:` to download the other data.